# Merge multiple geojson-polygons

Tags: vector, geojson, merge

Lets say I have a very big image With a polygon in it:

[image]

I want to polygonize this very big image with gdal polygonize. But the image is too big, so I dont have enough memory to polygonize that properly (I know there are some options but forget them for a while). So I split this image into 4 images (black lines are the borders of each image):

[image]

Now I polygonize these 4 images and I obtain 4 GeoJSON-files with 2 polygons each (one bigger white polygon, and one smaller blue polygon). Then I put all polygons into one GeoJSON so that I have a GeoJSON with 8 polygons with it. When I import it in any GIS software it looks like the first picture but when I want to choose the blue polygon, I have to click on all 4 parts. Because in fact the result looks like this (orange = border of polygon)

[image]

So I need a way to merge polygons so that neighbour-polygons of the same color get merged to one polygon.

My images are of course a little bit more complex but I had to simplify it to a circle to show the problem

Comment: Within a GIS software you're looking for a Dissolve tool. From there you could output a new GeoJSON that has it as a single shape.

Comment: Thanks! I made some research but could not find a proper way to use it with gdal. Do you know how to use it?

Comment: The first answer at [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85028/) uses gdal (ogr2org and requires spatialite support) and has the command line. And here's a [blog post tutorial](http://darrencope.com/2015/01/23/dissolve-shapefiles-using-ogr/). Note I'm not directly familiar with the process and am only providing resources I found. Alternatively [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/en/site/) is a fairly robust, extensible, free GIS software with a GUI that has a dissolve command built in. Might be overkill for what you want though.