# Dissolve using GDAL/OGR?

Tags: python, shapefile, gdal, ogr, dissolve

I'm trying to dissolve a shapefile according to a field using Python 2.7.10 and I don't want to use ArcPy.

Is there any way to do this using GDAL/OGR?

Comment: take a look here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/dissolve-polygons-based-on-attributes-with-python-shapely-fiona

Comment: Command line ogr2ogr solution at [Dissolve/aggregate polygons with ogr2ogr or gpc?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85028/dissolve-aggregate-polygons-with-ogr2ogr-or-gpc), should be adaptable to pure python solution without too much effort

Answer (score 3):

Using the QGIS Processing GDAL Dissolve algorithm and checking the log, you can find something like this:

> ogr2ogr /tmp/OUTPUT.shp /tmp/points.shp -nlt PROMOTE_TO_MULTI -dialect
>   sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry, \"DissolveID\"
>   FROM \"points\" GROUP BY \"DissolveID\"" -f "ESRI Shapefile"