# Dissolving polygon shapefile in Python without ArcPy?

Tags: python, gdal, ogr, shapely, fiona

I need to figure out a way to dissolve a polygon in Python using other modules besides ArcPy. I've been using the Python GDAL/OGR for merging shapefiles but I don't see anything to dissolve a polygon. I've been looking into Shapley, Fiona and Pyshp.

I also don't want to use qgis, as importing the qgis.core module gives my script problems.

Any ideas?

**EDIT I'm trying the Fiona approach but am having a hard time configuring it. I installed a .whl of it and it appears to install but when I run something it crashes Python saying

'This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way'

When I try to update the module in Pycharm, I get an error 'gdal version is not defined'

Comment: [Dissolve polygons based on attributes with Python (shapely - fiona)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149959/dissolve-polygons-based-on-attributes-with-python-shapely-fiona) or  [GeoPandas:Aggregation with dissolve](http://geopandas.org/aggregation_with_dissolve.html) for example

Comment: Can you call ogr2ogr with Sqlite ST_Union from Python or a shell script. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85028/dissolve-aggregate-polygons-with-ogr2ogr-or-gpc

Comment: Also, The Packt website has a nice Dissolve python script using Shapely, in chapter 6 of PythonGeospatialAnalysisCookbook code download.

Comment: @klewis That/those comment(s) could be worth adding as an answer on the duplicate.

Comment: It sounds like you now have a new question to research on "Configuring Fiona?"