# Is there an equivalent to the Dissolve all function in GDAL dissolve user interface?

Tags: qgis, gdal, dissolve

I am looking to compare the speed of the dissolve tool because the QGIS dissolve tool is performing very slow for me. However, I need to dissolve all the features into one so that I can create an outline of the perimeter of these.

The QGIS dissolve tool has this as a tick option (please see first image below).

Is it possible to do this with the GDAL UI?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dissolve/aggregate polygons with ogr2ogr or gpc?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85028/dissolve-aggregate-polygons-with-ogr2ogr-or-gpc)

Comment: Don't think there is such menu in the GUI. You could create a new field which contains the same value for all features (if there is currently no such field). Then use this field when running the GDAL tool for dissolve.