# ogr2ogr dissolve shapefile

Tags: ogr2ogr, dissolve

I am following this question with the first answer [Dissolve/aggregate polygons with ogr2ogr or gpc?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/85028/dissolve-aggregate-polygons-with-ogr2ogr-or-gpc) where I am trying to dissolve my shapefile down to 1 row by the geometry field

```
ogr2ogr C:\Users\name\Desktop\output.shp C:\Users\name\Desktop\All_constraints_v5.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM input"

ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM input):
 no such table: input
```

right so then I did

```
C:\Program Files\GDAL>ogrinfo -so C:\Users\rizagha\Desktop\All_constraints_v5.shp
INFO: Open of `C:\Users\rizagha\Desktop\All_constraints_v5.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: All_constraints_v5 (Polygon)
```

So my question is

1. `"SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM input"` does input need to be my shp full path variable? what is the exact syntax
2. I cannot find out what the geometry column is called.

I ran this:

```
C:\Program Files\GDAL>ogrinfo -geomfield -fields=YES C:\Users\rizagha\Desktop\All_constraints_v5.shp
INFO: Open of `C:\Users\rizagha\Desktop\All_constraints_v5.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: All_constraints_v5 (Polygon)
```

but it doesn't tell me what column name the geom is

Comment: As ogrinfo shows, your layer name is `All_constraints_v5` and that is what you will use for FROM. Geometry field is "geometry" for the SQLite dialect.

Comment: ahh gotcha okay that worked

Comment: @user30184 put it as answer so I can close this question out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As ogrinfo shows, the layer name is All_constraints_v5 and therefore the righ command is

```
ogr2ogr C:\Users\name\Desktop\output.shp C:\Users\name\Desktop\All_constraints_v5.shp -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM All_constraints_v5"
```